# There are strange indents between characters in WebStorm terminal

Tags: terminal, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Yesterday everything was fine, the problem occurred suddenly, I didn't touch the fonts.

[image: problem]

Changing the font in the settings does not help. I think this happened after yesterday's update.

Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i think this could be an error with a "non-mono" font.
I found this on the JetBrains Issue tracker site:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172886

When i understand the thread correctly you should either switch your terminal or you should switch to a mono font